# what functions or classes of functions are Riemann non-integrable but Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering if there are some other examples of Riemann non-integrable but Lebesgue integrable, besides the well-known Dirichlet function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yuval's link shows the general criterion for bounded functions on a bounded interval, namely continuity almost everywhere.  The Dirichlet function is a good example, but it is almost everywhere zero, and the zero function sure is Riemann integrable.  If you consider the characteristic function of a [Cantor set of positive measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), then it is not Riemann integrable because it is discontinuous at each point in this "fat" Cantor set, and you cannot modify the values on a set of measure 0 to fix this defect.

The same idea would work for any closed nowhere dense subset $E\subset[0,1]$ of positive measure, and you can appeal to the definition to see this.  Because every subinterval of $[0,1]$ has nonempty intersection with $[0,1]\setminus E$, the lower Riemann sums of $\chi_E$ are all $0$.  However, the upper Riemann sums are all bounded below by $m(E)\gt0$.

Comment: But why is the Dirichlet function not Riemann integrable? It is continuous at the irrationals, which have full measure.

Comment: @THeo: There are variants named the same. For instance, some people call the characteristic function of the rationals as a Dirichlet function (which is probably what OP meant).

Comment: @Theo,@Moron: Yes, I equate Dirichlet function and characteristic function of the rationals.

Comment: @Jonas,@Moron: Thanks for clearing this up...

Comment: @Theo: Are you're thinking of this function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function?

Comment: @Hans: Yes, exactly, thanks. I just looked at the graph here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html (first Google hit) without reading the fine print. But I'm sure I've never heard that name Thomae.

Answer (score 3):

For me the "canonical" example is the characteristic function of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$. The upper integral is one, the lower integral is zero.

**Edit:** Jonas and Moron have informed me that some people call this example Dirichlet function (and I vaguely remember that we might have done so as well in our Analysis class).

Comment: +1. This is the first one which comes to my mind when someone asks this question

Answer (score 2):

Check the Wikipedia article on the [Riemann integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) for some ideas.

Comment: I know the conclusion, but examples please!

Comment: @Qiang Li: In that case, it would be nice if you included more information in your question.  This is a very good answer to the question asked (rather than intended), especially as it asks "what functions or classes of functions are Riemann non-integrable but Lebesgue integrable?": This answer leads you to the class of bounded measurable functions on a bounded interval that are discontinuous on a set of positive measure as a partial answer.