# Why is this function continuous, unlike the Dirichlet function?

Tags: calculus, analysis

My teacher showed us this function and told us it was continuous at all non-$\mathbb{Q}$ points:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
  x & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q} \\\\
  0 & \text{ if }x\notin\mathbb{Q} \end{cases} $$

However, Wolfram MathWorld says [the Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html), which is very similar, is discontinuous at all points. Why is one continuous and the other not?

Comment: On the other hand, the second function listed on that MathWorld page _is_ a good example of a function continuous at each irrational and discontinuous at the rationals. It's harder to prove that the reverse situation cannot occur.

Comment: Here's an article for those interested in (but not familiar with) @Dylan's statement: http://www.maa.org/mathdl/MM/0025570x.di021166.02p0055m.pdf

Comment: Please.  Read this: Wikipedia:Manual of Style/Mathematics/Why you should never use \mbox within Wikipedia  This does not apply ONLY to Wikipedia.

Comment: The function your teacher showed you is not continuous at all irrationals (nor is it discontinuous at all rationals).  It is, however, a nice example of a function which is continuous only at a single point (namely 0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As <del>other answers have</del> Henning's answer has explained already, your teacher is wrong. However, my guess is that s/he was confusing your function with this related one:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, &\text{ if $x$ is irrational},
\\\\
1/b, &\text{ if $x = a/b$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$}.
\end{cases}
$$
This function does have the property that it is continuous at all irrational points, and discontinuous at the rationals.

**Source:** Look at the "modified Dirichlet function" $D_M(x)$ in [the Mathworld article on the Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html.).

*Edit:* It turns out that @lhf posted the same answer independently, but he links to the Wikipedia page of the function: [click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function).

**Terminology:** I just learned<sup>1</sup> that this function is usually called **Thomae's function**, and not the modified Dirichlet function. I have known this example for some time, but not by any specific name. Wikipedia lists a number of other interesting names as well: the Riemann function, the popcorn function, the Stars over Babylon, the raindrop function, and the ruler function.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the post [what functions or classes of functions are Riemann non-integrable but Lebesgue integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18388/what-functions-or-classes-of-functions-are-riemann-non-integrable-but-lebesgue-in), Hans Lundmark's comment (under Jonas Meyer's answer) gives the name of the function and the wikipedia link. Thanks to Theo Buehler for sharing the post.

Comment: That's a very nice answer now! However, I don't really deserve any credit, but rather Hans Lundmark, see the comment thread to Jonas's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18388).

Answer (score 5):

Your teacher is wrong. Every neighborhood of any real number contains both rational and non-rational points, so the function is continuous at 0 only.

More specifically, let $\alpha$ be a positive irrational number (in particular $\alpha\ne0$, and the argument for negative irrationals is almost the same). Let's check whether $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$. For this to hold, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there must be a $\delta$ such that
$$ |x-\alpha|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(\alpha)|<\epsilon $$
Since $f(\alpha)=0$, the right-hand side of this is equivalent to $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.

As I'm going to prove that $f$ is *not* continuous at $\alpha$, I have the right to select $\epsilon$, and then I must prove that there's no $\delta$ that works for it. I choose $\epsilon=\alpha/2$. Now, for every possible positive $\delta$, the interval $(\alpha, \alpha+\delta)$ is open and therefore contains at least one rational number, which we can call $R$. Then, setting $x=R$ we get $|R-\alpha|<\delta$ (by construction), but $|f(R)|=R>\alpha$ is certainly *larger* than $\epsilon$, which was $\alpha/2$. Thus, $\delta$ fails to work, as promised.

Comment: Another way is to use the fact that a function $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff for all sequences $x_n \to x$, the sequence $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. Any $x$ can be approached by both rational and irrational sequences $x_n$; the corresponding limits of $f(x_n)$ then are equal to $x$ and $0$ respectively. For continuity, we require $x = 0$.

Comment: That works, too -- but for the purpose of convincing an errant teacher to mend his ways, I think it is useful to go as close to the definitions as practically possible. (I think epsilon-delta definitions are more common at the elementary calculus level than sequential continuity, but I may be wrong in the instant case, of course).

Comment: You are right, I do not think they do sequential continuity in the elementary calculus classes. I just pointed it out for completeness sake; I am not claiming any one way is easier than the other.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps your teacher meant [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), which is continuous at all irrational numbers and discontinuous at all rational numbers.